# GPIO pin (BCM 12) acts differently on PI3 and PI4

Tags: python, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio, pi-4

The following code is running on PI3 and is working perfectly fine. I try to provide a short description of what the code does. In this code I first set the BCM 12 as the pin of interest for my sensor which is a proximity sensor. Normally the pin is 1 unless I put something close to sensor in which case pin becomes 0. I pasted main parts of the code for your reference down here (I did not paste the whole code here). Now question is when I use the same code in PI4, it acts differently. Even without anything close to the proximity sensor, the pin is 0. In fact the pin always stays at zero. Expected behavior is: pin BCM 12 should stay 1 unless I put something next to sensor and in that case it should change into 0. But on PI4, it always stays at 0.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  # pylint: disable=import-error

PROXIMITY_SENSOR_GPIO_CHANNEL = 12
LED_GPIO_CHANNEL = 20


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PROXIMITY_SENSOR_GPIO_CHANNEL, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(LED_GPIO_CHANNEL, GPIO.OUT)


# this function checks whether the pin is triggered
def is_sample_present():
    return GPIO.input(PROXIMITY_SENSOR_GPIO_CHANNEL) == 0

def setup_proximity_callback():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(
        PROXIMITY_SENSOR_GPIO_CHANNEL,
        GPIO.RISING,
        proximity_sensor_callback,
        bouncetime=1
    )
```

Comment: Looking at [this graphic](https://img.purch.com/gpio-pi4-final-png/o/aHR0cDovL21lZGlhLmJlc3RvZm1pY3JvLmNvbS9VL00vODQzNTAyL29yaWdpbmFsL0dQSU8tUGk0LUZpbmFsLnBuZw==) it looks like on the Pi 4, BCM 12 is both GPIO 18 and SPI6 CEO IN. You may have to disable SPI on the Pi 4.

Comment: Shouldn't it still act as GPIO 12? Can you elaborate on what you mean? I am totally new with these names. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the graphic, its the pinout for Raspberry Pis. It has a marking (the big boxed 4) for things that only apply on the Pi 4. If you look at pin 12, it shows that it's GPIO 18, but also next to a big boxed 4 that it's SPI6 CEO IN (you can learn about SPI and I2C [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial/all)). My guess is that SPI might need to be disabled for the pin to act as GPIO. But SPI is disabled by default, so unless you've enabled it, this isn't the solution.

Comment: You can check if SPI is enabled with `sudo raspi-config`, navigating to `Advanced Options`->`SPI`.

Comment: For some reason, when I disable it, the code crashes. Once I enable it again, previous situation occurs.

Comment: There should be no difference as far as GPIO12 is concerned.  Why is your callback for RISING if the alarm is going to 0?  Most likely is you have wired to the wrong GPIO.  Photo?

Comment: I don't think that is causing the issue. I have the exactly the same code on PI 3 and it works totally fine. I changed it to FALLING and same result. here ie the link to the photo. All conditions are the same except a different pi. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cshqhkpkgin5p0i/IMG_8815.HEIC?dl=0

Comment: Here I put the config file of the two PIs. Do you think something is missing in PI4. 
PI3 config: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b0nbfvshjgsipg/config_PI3.txt?dl=0


PI4 config: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1tu9zkg09ar50l/config_PI4.txt?dl=0

Comment: "The code crashes"... An error message would be helpful.

Comment: @joan You're right, I had BCM mode and board mode mixed up.

Comment: Sure, follow this link for the error message. This error appears when I disable SPI.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx2e62kbllcplyc/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Sorry previous link does not work. Please try this link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dup6g0clyzdr802/Screen%20Shot%202019-09-07%20at%205.36.23%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Well that answers at least part of my question. The line that is throwing the error is `self.spi.xfer2([0] * 4)`. I dug through that code and realized its a library for controlling a full SPI device. Your error is not caused by anything to do with pin 12, since BCM pin 12 is not an SPI pin (I was mistaken earlier). If you are controlling a PCI device (which that library was built to do exactly that) you will need SPI *enabled*. Again, that error has nothing to do with pin 12, it's an error that happens when you go to control your APA102 LED (DotStar).

Comment: Instead of running your entire script, which is clearly more complicated than just reading high/low from a pin, try writing a minimum working example of just reading high/low from a pin and running that across the two Pis. That would be miles easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickCook. Do you have any guess what might be causing this?

Comment: My guess as to what is causing the difference between the two Pis is user error. Something must be configured differently between them. Make sure you have all the necessary dependencies installed properly, your physical wiring is correct, etc. Sometimes errors that look so complicated come down to something as simple as a missing comma.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickCook . I went ahead and did what you recommended. On both PI3 and PI4 I tried to implement the following code. Again, PI3 detects the event but PI4 does not detect the event at all. Can you tell what could be missing based on the following code?                    
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbvxlqp1ibdpbmo/test_port.py?dl=0

Comment: From the code itself, no I can't. However this is good progress. I would suggest seeing if the Pi 4's GPIO works at all. Try just writing a script that turns a pin on or off, and test that pin with a voltmeter or an LED. If that fails, then we know something else is going on.

Comment: ```sudo apt-get update``` and ```sudo apt-get upgrade``` solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` solved the problem.